# Add values to array using for loop

Tags: javascript

I know this is pretty simple with php, but in javascript it's harder for me.

I want the output to be as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "message": "..."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "message": "..."
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "message": "..."
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "message": "..."
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "message": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this, but it did not as expected.

```
var data = [];
var array = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"];
array.forEach((messsage, key) => {
    data["data"] = {
        id: key + 1,
        message: messsage
    }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `data['data']` should be `data[key]` - better use map like shown below though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data["data"]` assigns to the property `data` on the `data` variable. You should use `.map` instead, which is more appropriate than `forEach` when transforming one array into another:

```js
var array = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"];
var data = array.map((message, i) => ({
  id: i + 1,
  message
}));
console.log(data);
```

If you *were* to use `forEach`, the right way to fix your original code would be to `push` to `data` on every iteration:

```js
var data = [];
var array = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"];
array.forEach((messsage, key) => {
  data.push({
    id: key + 1,
    message: messsage
  })
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: It was not what I expected but anyway I solved my problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `data` you want is not the `data` you create. It seems you want to create an `Object` from an `Array`, containing one property: `data`. You can do that in one go, using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
const data = {
  data: ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"]
    .map( (value, index) => ( {id: index + 1, message: value} ) )
};
```

You can create a more generic function for it:

```js
console.log(createData("message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"));

function createData(...messages) {
  // 'messages' can be an array, or a number of arguments
  messages = messages[0].constructor === Array ? messages[0] : Array.from(messages)
  return {
    data: messages
      .map( (value, index) => ( {id: index + 1, message: value} ) )
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
var data = [];
var array = ["message 1", "message 2", "message 3", "message 4", "message 5"];
var key=0;
array.forEach((element) => {
key=key+1
data.push({
    "id": key,
    "message": element[key-1]
})
 });
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why and not just write `Here is an example`.

Comment: Foreach wander over the records. Returns each record set of the array. It allows you to do things with Callback. In the example I added messages to the empty Array with Callback.

Comment: I ment to extend the answer with an explanation and not to write that as comment. Beside that you changed the answer to something that does not work anymore, and why do now use a `key` variable you incrment, instead of using the index provided by the `forEach`.